# Bootstrap: Scroll Model to Center Focused Field

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to make a modal automatically scroll when a form field inside it is focused in order to center it? I think it would be useful when dealing with form in mobile devices with  virtual keyboards

**UPDATE**

Try this bootply http://www.bootply.com/2tPE0xj7GX# with your smartphone and fill the form fields. You will notice the keyboard overlaps the fields

Comment: I dont want to sound like a wisecrack, but what phone doesn't center the viewport on an input that gets focussed?

Comment: I have found a bootply with a form showing what I mean. Try it with your smartphone

Answer (score 0):

As I said. On every sane mobile OS the focussed input should get perfectly centered in the remaining screen portion. It at least does so on iOS.

[image: iOS Screenshot]

Comment: you are right it does on my iPhone 6 but it doesn't on my Nexus 5 :(